# While loop in bash script breaks systemd service

Tags: linux, bash, debian, systemd

I'm on Debian and I have a systemd service that calls a bash script.

The script contains an infinite while loop, as I need it to check something every X seconds infinitely.

The systemd service crashes once it hits the "while true; do" line.

The script runs fine if I execute it manually.
Why doesn't systemd like it? What do I do?

Here are the service and the script. As I've indicated, an echo statement before the "while true; do" prints. The echo statement after the "while true; do" line does not print.

/etc/systemd/system/stream.service:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/
ExecStart=/home/pi/joi_main.sh
Restart=no
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=stream_service
User=pi
Group=pi
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/home/pi/joi_main.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

today=`/bin/date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`
exec 2> "/home/pi/stream_logs/$today.$RANDOM.log"
exec 1>&2

#Wait 120s for system to finish booting
sleep 120

#Initial config
export AUDIODEV=mic_mono
export AUDIODRIVER=alsa
sudo sysctl fs.pipe-max-size=1048576

echo "This line prints"

# Check if video buffer is full every minute. if full, the stream needs to restart
while true; do
    echo "This line doesn't"
    if grep "100% full" /home/pi/video_buffer_usage.txt; then
        echo "Buffer is full!"
    # Kill existing processes
        pkill -f “raspivid|rec|buffer|ffmpeg”
    # Wait 10s
         sleep 10
         ./joi_stream.sh &
    fi
    sleep 60
done
```

Journalctl seems completely unhelpful, but here it is. No errors. Why is "session closed"?

```
Mar 31 02:13:41 raspberrypi sudo[1369]: pi : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/sysctl fs.pipe-max-size=1048576
Mar 31 02:13:41 raspberrypi sudo[1369]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 31 02:13:41 raspberrypi sudo[1369]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

(Please don't tell me to start yet another systemd service for just this while loop. I want it to be part of this main script because it needs to run after everything else, and if I turn off the main service I don't want the while loop running either, so maintaining two systemd services would only add troube.)

Comment: Please include your service definition file.

Comment: I've done so, let me know if I can add anything else

Comment: What if you change it to `while :; do`?

Comment: `:` is a built-in command that's always successful, so this avoids having to find `/bin/true` to execute.

Comment: Barmar: I tried that, still never reaches echo "This line doesn't". While /bin/true; do also doesn't work.

Comment: There's a call to `sudo` on line 13. Does the user `pi` have a `NOPASSWD` rule for `sysctl` in the `sudoers` file? If not, the script will hang there waiting for password input.

Answer (score 3):

The contents of `./joi_stream.sh` were not shared, but here's a problem I see with your `systemd` solution. It doesn't directly explain your behavior, but may be related:

In your `systemd` configuration, you redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to `syslog`, but in your script, you redirect STDERR (file descriptor "2") to a file, and redirect STDOUT (file descriptor "1') to STDERR.

```
exec 2> "/home/pi/stream_logs/$today.$RANDOM.log"
exec 1>&2
```

If your `./joi_stream.sh` expected your redirection of these file descriptors to another file to work, it may not. If the file is just for logging, I would get rid of these lines and let the systemd journal handle that-- it will tag the logs with your unit you can review your logs specifically:

```
 journalctl -u your-unit-name.service
```

Also, in `systemd`, you wouldn't normally put in a sleep to wait until the systemd has booted. Instead, you would use a `.timer` unit.

The `.timer` file would instruct to run the main logic every minute, so the "while" loop would not be required. The timer unit would contain directives like:

# Run for the first time 2 minutes after boot 
   # and every minute after that
   OnBootSec=120 
   OnUnitActiveSec=60

It would be *timer* unit which is *enabled* to start on boot. Timer files can be super-simple. Just create a `.timer` file in `/etc/systemd/system` and give it the same name as the service file you want it to activate:

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs my service every minute

[Timer]
# Run for the first time 2 minutes after boot 
# and every minute after that
OnBootSec=120 
OnUnitActiveSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

To start and test your timer immediately, run:

```
sudo systemctl start my-service.timer
```

You can review the status of timers with:

```
sudo systemctl list-timers
```

The `systemd` solution is more robust than the `rc.local` solution. If your `rc.local` solution dies for any reason, it will not restart.  However, if your script dies will run under `systemd`, the timer will still run it again a minute later.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, everything works if I call /home/pi/joi_main.sh from /etc/rc.local instead of using a systemd service. I'll use rc.local and kill the service.